# Make array of variables?

Tags: android

First let me state, that I am still new to Android.
I need to send a group of variables to a secondary activity. I think the fastest way is with something like Intent, but my problem is that my variables are in loop and change value with each cycle of loop. If the loop goes 5 times my variables change  value 5 times, etc.  I need to transfer each of these 5 values in other activities to make a custom list. Can I make an array of variables or something like that? Maybe I can make a list in one activity and just show it in other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can ad an arrayList of integers, strings, or paracelables as an extra for an intent

**from the first activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
i.putIntegerArrayListExtra(name, value);
i.putStringArrayListExtra(name, value);
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(name, value);
```

**in the second Activity onCreate()**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> myStrings = i.getStringArrayListExtra(name);
```

Comment: why use it is a better question.. just pass the whole array. if you loop you have to loop twice just to pass it..

Comment: I parse some text in for loop and for example in for i gething
Name:SomeName
Number:SomeNumber
than loop going one more time
Name:SomeName1
Number:SomeNumber1

If i use this method? how to get all Name and Number values?

Comment: ? what? i don't understand what you are saying

Comment: @erik sorry , i press enter earlier, now i changed comment